# stops become blank squares in cjhebrew

Tags: punctuation, hebrew

The following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\begin{document}
\begin{cjhebrew}
hd .
\end{cjhebrew}
\end{document}
```

Generates the correct hebrew letters, but the stop (dot) becomes a blank square: `� הד`.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill - changed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cjHebrew` package was meant for writing biblical text. Those usually have no punctuation marks such as periods and commas - instead there is the colon that symbolizes end-of-sentence, etc.

For your question - note that `cjhebrew` treats dots and commas as part of the translation, e.g. `.s` produces `צ` and `,s` produces `שׂ`. You cannot use periods and commas with their regular meaning inside a `cjhebrew` environment. A suggested solution is to push periods and commas outside. e.g., type `\cjRL{hd}.` instead of the code you gave as an example.

If you write a full paragraph, surround the periods and commas with `\textrm{.}` to temporarily switch back rm-font.

Comment: If I understood correctly, both Your solutions will not work: 
1. if I put each word in a `\cjRL{}` with commas and dots between then the order of the sentences is reversed in each line (because the line is still parsed left to right).
2. if I put `\cjLR{.,}` I get two empty boxes

Comment: yes, you're right, I was misreading the manual, and skip testing. `\textrm` works here, or any other command that enforces a non-hebrew font. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a stop character in cjhebrew.  The LaTeX input ";" will yield a ":" in the appropriate font, which is a common stop character in modern typesetting of biblical Hebrew.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[body={7in,9in}]{geometry}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{38pt}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\begin{document}

  \fontsize{\mylength}{1.2\mylength}\selectfont
  \begin{cjhebrew}
    +s:ma{\fontsize{1.2\mylength}{1.4\mylength}\selectfont `} yi,s:rA'el yhwh 'E:loheynw* yhwh 'E.hA{\fontsize{1.2\mylength}{1.4\mylength}\selectfont d};

    b*Arw*k: +sem k:bwod mal:kw*two l:`wolAm wA`Ed;\\[4mm]

    w:'Ahab:t*A 'et yhwh 'E:lohEykA b*:kAl--l:bAb:kA w*b:kAl--nap:+s:kA w*b:kAl--m:'odEkA\\[2mm]
    w:hAyw* had:bArym hA'elEh 'a:+sEr 'Anokiy m:.saw:kA haywom `al--l:bAbEkA\\[2mm]
    w:+sinan:t*Am l:bAnEykA w:dib*ar:t*A b*Am\\[2mm] b*:+sib:t*:kA b*:beytEkA w*b:lEk:t*:kA badErEk: w*b:+sAk:b*:kA w*b:qw*mEkA\\[2mm]
    w*q+sar:t*Am l:'wot `al--yAdEkA w:hAyw* l:.to.tApot b*eyn `eynEkA\\[2mm]
    w*k:tab:t*Am `al--m:zuzwot b*eytEkA w*bi+s:`ArEykA;
  \end{cjhebrew}

\end{document}
```